how to recover a deleted Source code page from the navigation bar on VSC?
how to recover a deleted Source code page from the navigation bar on VSC?
recover it using terminal window ( MacOS ), but didnt work, instead i get stucked!!
Anyone with the same experience, i'd appreciate your help or anny suggestions?

/Edit: It appears that this question is already answered on StackOverflow here, so I guess this question should be marked as already having an answer.
My original answer (which is now obsolete):
There is a feature called Local History in VSCode.
It is described in How I restored my deleted file in VSCode: A cool trick you should know.
In case that page is ever to be deleted I'll quote its important parts here:
How I got my file back

Open command palette

First, I opened the Command Palette by pressing Cmd+Shift+P

Find the local history command

Then, I pasted the phrase "Local History: Find Entry to Restore" in the Command Palette. It popped up in the list, so I pressed Enter.

Search for my deleted file

Next, it asked me to type the name of the file I deleted. I did, and to my happy surprise, my deleted file was there!

Choose the right version

After pressing Enter, I was presented with a list of snapshots of my file that VSCode remembered for me. I picked the most recent version and pressed Enter again.

Restore the file

Finally, just like that, VSCode restored the contents of my file! It was like magic! I was so happy. Then it sufficed to just save this file contents on my disk with the hotkey Cmd+S and I could commit it now with Git.
